# How can I tell if a user group modification event is triggered due to group policy instead of manual action?

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-event-log

I'm to trigger an alert if users are *manually* added to an administrators group based on the content of a windows event.

Here's an example of the event (with some stuff sanitized)

```
{
  "hostIdentifier": "00000000-abcd-ef12-3456-1234567890",
  "MemberName": "-",
  "MemberSid": "S-1-5-XX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX",
  "PrivilegeList": "-",
  "SubjectDomainName": "FOO",
  "SubjectLogonId": "0x3e7",
  "SubjectUserName": "EXAMPLEUSER-FOO$",
  "SubjectUserSid": "S-1-5-18",
  "TargetDomainName": "Builtin",
  "TargetSid": "S-1-5-32-123",
  "TargetUserName": "FooAdmins",
  "datetime": "2020-09-01T20:12:10.123456789Z",
  "eventid": "4732",
  "keywords": "-1",
  "level": "0",
  "provider_guid": "{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX}",
  "provider_name": "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing",
  "source": "Security",
  "task": "13826",
  "time": "1234567890"
}
```

The only thing I think I can key off of is the `SubjectUserSid` and the fact that it's a system account (as per `$`).  Even then though, it doesn't explicitly indicate that it was the result of a group policy action. Is there an obvious flag in the event that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can reliably tell whether it was done manually. The subject can be a user account and still be a scripted, automated action. It can also be a service account used for automation, but still be manually triggered with custom parameters.

Best you can do is an educated guess. Users are not automatically added to any administrators groups. So you could always trigger the alert and start from there.

- If you install a software that adds users to admin groups, just ignore the alert or mark it as resolved.
- If you have mechanisms that add users to administrator groups, make exceptions when you see the service account in the event item.
- Otherwise generate the alert.

As an additional filter, you could correlate the SubjectLogonId with a logon event and check the logon type. If it's interactive, you can be quite certain it was a manual task. However, it could still be an automated action and logon type network could still be a manual action.